# How can I make this square-inside-square structure horizontal?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to represent this structure horizontaly, but I'm having some issues on what should I change so that this can work properly. What I hope to achieve is that those small squares in the bottom appear the same, only verticaly, on top of each other, while the bigger square keeps it's model.

```css
.date-grid {
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.node {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #e9ecef;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
}

time {
    display: block;
    height: 75%;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
  
.smallHolder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    display: flex;
}
  
.smallHolder>div {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
  
.next { background: #0060df; }  

.last { background: #d53343; }
```

```html
<div class="date-grid">
    <button class="node">
        <time>3</time>
        <div class="smallHolder">
            <div class="next"></div>
            <div class="last"></div>
        </div>   
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the sort of thing you're looking for? [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) is great for this sort of thing.

```css
.date-grid {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 120px 25px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "gray next" "gray last";
  padding: 0;
  border-style: none;
}

.gray {
  grid-area: gray;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background: #e9ecef;
}

time {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.next {
  grid-area: next;
  background: #0060df;
}

.last {
  grid-area: last;
  background: #d53343;
}
```

```html
<button class="node date-grid">
  <time class='gray'>3</time>
  <div class="next"></div>
  <div class="last"></div>
</button>
```

Comment: Yes, it's precisely this I need, thank you.